# Bootstrap-vue: How to hide the v-b-tooltip when you hover on the tooltip itself (not the button)

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I have buttons that are close to each other that when the tooltip pops out it would block the other buttons out, here's a picture of the said problem:

[image: the problem]

If I hover the request button below the other one and then tries to hover the button above it, I will end up hovering on the tooltip instead of the button below it.

I can hide the tooltip on hover (see code below) using CSS but it produces a flickering effect when I hover to the next button then ends up not showing the tooltip on that specific next button.

```css
.tooltip:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

So my questions would be:

1. Is there a property on `bootstrap-vue` that would only show the tooltip when hovered on the button itself;
2. or hide the tooltip when hovering the tooltip itself;
3. If none, any alternative that would replicate the behavior I wanted without needing to change or edit each existing button on my app (*preferred*).

Comment: Would it be helpfull to [reposition the tooltips on the left and on the right](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/directives/tooltip/#positioning)?

Comment: @wittgenstein That was what I thought at first, but the problem would persist on adjacent buttons. I have some tables with four buttons that are close to each other so this wouldn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `noninteractive` modifier on the directive. (or prop if you're using the component)

This will make it so the tooltip can't be interacted with, so hovering the tooltip wont keep it visible.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-5">
  <b-button v-b-tooltip.noninteractive.hover title="Try and hover me!">
    Hover me
  </b-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Completely missed that! Is it better in any way, like performance-wise than my answer? If none, I won't be bothered in changing my existing fix that I've implemented for each button in my app . Though, I would choose this as the answer as it is more inline with bootstrap-vue rather than my hacky approach.

Comment: Also can you think of an alternative solution using CSS, so that I'll just write the code once on my stylesheet instead of editing the each existing button property on my app?

Comment: If you're using the component `<b-tooltip>` you can use the [configuration](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/settings#configuring-defaults) to set up global defaults for props. However I don't recall whether these also work for directives.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use the component itself, only its property equivalent for my buttons, but what you've shared is definitely the right direction, I'll try to make it work on my `nuxt` config

Comment: It seems to only work on components. Wasn't able to make it work on my `nuxt.config.js` file sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

Add an event listener as to when the mouse leaves/(un)hover the button and hide all tooltips:

```html
<button
  v-b-tooltip.hover="'Edit This Bish'"
  @mouseleave="$root.emit('bv::hide::tooltip')"
>
  The Button
</button>
```

The con with this is that you'll have to edit this to all existing buttons on other tables. That's why I'm still open to other more easier and general solution than this.

Boostrap-vue Documentation: [How to hide all open tooltips](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/directives/tooltip#hiding-and-showing-tooltips-via-root-events)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't use bootstrap components like me, you can use the **noninteractive** directive instead:

```html
<div v-b-tooltip.noninteractive="{title: `I'm a tooltip`}">Hover me!</div>
```

For futher reference: [tooltip directives](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/directives/tooltip)